# Linear algebra matrix help

Tags: linear-algebra

If a system of N linear equations in N unknowns is represented by the product of a coefficient matrix and a column vector , and each row in that coefficient matrix is linearly independent, does that imply the system has a unique solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** (Taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix))

The following are equivalent:

1) $A$ is invertible

2) $A^t$ is invertible

3) The columns of $A$ are linearly independent

Comment: I don't understand is it the columns or the rows? which has to be linearly independent both? or one of them?

Comment: $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^t$ is invertible.  This means that te columns of $A$ are linearly independent if and only if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent.  If eany of these conditions are met, then $A$ is invertible, and hence has a unique solution $x = A^{-1} b$.

Answer (score 0):

yes it has a unique solution

for the problem :$Ax=0$ where $A$ = coefficient matrix  $x$ = column vector has only $1$ solution which is $x=0$ (as the rows of $A$ are linearly independent $\implies A $ can be reduced to $I_{n\times n}$,hence finding the solution of $Ax=0$  is  same as finding the solution for $I_{n\times n}x=0$).

for the problem :$Ax=y$ there will be only one solution $x=A^{-1} \cdot y$

Answer (score 0):

It implies that the coefficient matrix $A$ is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Properties).
 Therefore the system $Ax=b$ has the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b.$